# How to make a horizontal scroll for left-floating children?

Tags: html, css

I have a container wrapper div that I want to stretch the width of it's parent, so I set it to 100% width. I want to have children divs in it that if they are wider than the wrapper, it will just add a horizontal scroll. You can check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rF6WA/) here to see my problem. I don't want the 4th element to be on a new line, but rather outside of the borders of the `wrapper` div and have it create a horizontal scroll. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach would be setting the elements to `inline-block`, and then using `white-space: nowrap` to prevent them from breaking to a new line. Aside from that, you were missing a semi-colon after `overflow-x:scroll`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/e4aZA/)

```
.element {
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0f0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you absolutely have to use floating element, you would essentially have to wrap the elements with another element, which has a larger width.

Answer (score 0):

Following css will provide horizontal scroll. To get vertical scroll use overflow: scroll;

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 30%;
}
```