# CSS Float is wrapping

Tags: html, css

This is probably and easy fix but I searched online without any luck.

I have a div that is snapped to the bottom of a page. That div contains button items that need to be stacked side by side ... I am doing that by using FLOAT but what happens is that the extra content is wrapped naturally and i am getting multiple rows of the buttons ...

What I need is a long row of buttons next to each other so that the long bar is fixed and scrollable left to right.

Please see visual problem here

[image]

[image]

The current code as is .... the entire containing div is called "footer" and here is the code

```
#footer {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#b6b6b6;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  padding:10px;
}
```

The individual button divs are called "footerItems" and here is the code

```
.footerItems {
   float:left;
   padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you not want there to be a scrollbar either?

Comment: See **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603660/how-to-make-a-horizontal-scroll-for-left-floating-children)** ... you basically need to change them to `inline-block` elements, and then use `white-spae:nowrap` ... change the overflow if you want a scrollbar.. If you absolutely must use floated elements, just wrap the elements.

Comment: If using `display: inline-block`, be aware that [whitespace is rendered between the elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). This is normal and per the spec, just unexpected by many developers.

Comment: I enjoy how you use a website to display an image ^^

Comment: They didn't let me upload pictures since i don't have enough reputation points :) so i had to get creative.

Comment: thank you guys ... the inline block solution worked and yes i need scrollbar for that. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it with floating elements. What you can do is using inline-block instead of float.

```
.footerItems {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right:10px;
}
```

For that you need to add `white-space: nowrap` so the elements wont break.

```
#footer {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#b6b6b6;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  padding:10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I guess you don't want to "see" the overflowing elements, so you have to add `overflow: hidden` to `#footer` too. Otherwise the parent-div would grow. Optional you can change `hidden` to `scroll` or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

simply set .footerItems display to inline-block and add whitespace:nowrap to the footer #footer

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I always prefer to set the width of the container to the total width of its children using javascript.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nY7ad/)

```
var $container = $('div');
var $children = $container.children();
var totalWidth = 0;

$children.each(function (i, child) {
    totalWidth += $(child).outerWidth(true);
});

$container.width(totalWidth);
```